# Fetch POST request console.log not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, json, post, fetch-api

While I can post data to my server, and the server `console.log` works, I cannot for the life figure out why the client side `console.log` isn't working. What am I missing here?

The Error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Status: `200 OK`

Request: `{"hotSauceId":32,"presentation":5,"viscosityId":3,"spiciness":10,"Flavor_Notes":["Constituent Peppers"],"overall_rating":5,"lovedit":true,"taster_notes":"test"}`

Looks json to me?

Submit Handler:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => { 
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://jyh:3000', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
          "hotSauceId": sauce,
          "presentation": presentation,
          "viscosityId": viscosity,
          "spiciness": spiciness,
          "Flavor_Notes": flavor,
          "overall_rating": overall,
          "lovedit": loved,
          "taster_notes": notes
      }),
      }).then(res => {
          return res.json();
      }).then(data => {
          console.log(data);
      }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Server Code:

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    await Jyh.create({  // .create is a Sequelize method
        hotSauceId: req.body.hotSauceId,
        presentation: req.body.presentation,
        viscosityId: req.body.viscosityId,
        spiciness: req.body.spiciness,
        Flavor_Notes: req.body.Flavor_Notes,
        overall_rating: req.body.overall_rating,
        lovedit: req.body.lovedit,
        taster_notes: req.body.taster_notes
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('req.body: ', req.body);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

It should console.log the response in the client console, but instead I receive an error.

[Github repository](https://github.com/Younion/new-app) for the client and server app.

Comment: Your server-side endpoint doesn't seem like it's returning anything at all. Does it need to? What are you expecting to receive in the client? The error is related to parsing the _response_ not the request.

Comment: I was hoping to get a console log on the client of the body I built. I suppose I just feel it's best practice to do so in case of any problems.

Comment: You're not sending any response body back though. If you want to have something to read on the client, you the server needs to send something.